# How to keep previous uploaded image after submitting a form without selecting a new image to be uploaded in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, codeigniter

I have a simple form that displays an image gallery along with title, image and date. My problem is with the image input.

Selecting a new one and submitting everything works fine but when I'm not selecting any image it saves blank data in the image field.

Is there a way to save the form with the image change being optional?

**Controller Code**

```
public function submitwedding()
{
    if(isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit']=='EDIT')
    {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'],'uploadimg/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

        $data = array('title'=>$_POST['edit1'],'avatar'=>$_FILES['avatar']['name'],'date'=>$_POST['date']);

        $this->Dbfunction->updatedata('wedding',$data,$_POST['id']);

        redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/wedding');
    }
}
```

**Front End Coding**

```
<tr>
    <td width="25%" >Title</td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="70%"><input type="text" name="edit1" id="title" style="width:250px"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->title ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr height="10px"></tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%" >image</td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="70%">
      <input type="file" name="avatar" value="<?php echo $row->avatar;?> "  id="avatar" size="20" /><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploadimg/<?php echo $row->avatar; ?>"/>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%" >Date</td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="70%"><input type="text" name="date" id="date" style="width:250px"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->date ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

**Dbfunction Coding**

```
function selectdatabyid($table , $id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('select * from '.$table.' where id='.$id);
    return $query->row();
}
function updatedata($table , $data , $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);
}
function deletedata($table, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($table);
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow community doesn't welcomes find-error-in-my-code-d questions.

Comment: just do one thing : take one hidden variable and save ur previous image name in to it and check if the file is not uploaded then use that hidden variable value. hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you leave the `value=""` attribute for the image-form-tag empty? When the user submits without selecting a new picture to upload, don't update the field in the database.

Just add an `if` into your php code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['avatar'])) {
    // update avatar because input is not empty
}
```